# Prove that $Ax=\mu x+\nu y\;$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$.

> Let $A\in\mathcal{B}(F)$. Assume that there is unit vector $x\in F$ such that $\langle Ax, x\rangle:=\mu \in \mathbb{C}$. Why there are unit vector $y\in F$ and $\nu\geq 0$ such that
>   $$Ax=\mu x+\nu y\;?$$

**My attempt:** Since $x$ is a unit vector, then $x\neq 0$. So,
$$F=\text{span}(x)\oplus \text{span}(x)^\perp.$$
So, since $Tx\in F$ then $Ax=\alpha x+x_2$ with $x_2\in \text{span}(x)^\perp$. Clearly $\alpha =\mu$. Why
$$x_2=\nu y \;?$$
with $\|y\|=1$ and $\nu\geq 0$.

I think one can write $x_2$ as $x_2=\frac{x_2}{\|x_2\|}\times \|x_2\|$ but perhaps $x_2$ is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Ax = \mu x$, you can choose any $y$ and $\nu=0$. Otherwise, choose
$$
y = \frac{Ax-\mu x}{\|Ax-\mu x\|}\quad\text{and}\quad\nu = \|Ax-\mu x\|.
$$
The information that $\langle Ax,x\rangle = \mu$ is superfluous.

Comment: Why it is superfluous? please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: It *is* superfluous because I did not use that information in my proof.

Comment: but $\mu$ is correct.

Comment: @Schüler What? What do you mean by "correct"? How can a number ($\mu$) be "correct"?

Comment: I mean the expression of $\mu$ is correct.

Comment: If you want help, be precise in what you say. Otherwise I'll be gone very quickly. What is "the expression of $\mu$"?

Comment: thank you. The expression of $\mu$ is given in the proof.

Comment: Ok, Schüler, I'm out. I asked you two questions about what you mean with "blabla" and "blabla", but you were not able to answer these questions. It's your own fault. Goodbye.